# Finding out the common users with licences type in same column by using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have a unpivoted table where i have users id, attribute, calculated column (license type test) and value. Now i need to find the count of users having all 3 license in common. [Table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTTo3.jpg)

Measure = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('User Details Unpivot'[User ID]), SELECTEDVALUE('User Details Unpivot'[Licence type test]) = "License1" && SELECTEDVALUE('User Details Unpivot' [Licence type test]) = "License2")&& SELECTEDVALUE('User Details Unpivot' [Licence type test]) = "License3")